# How to use here maps SDK for Swift 3?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, here-api

I am trying to use the here maps SDK and I tried every step as mentioned on the provided link:

https://developer.here.com/news/20170208a#.WVn1zNN968p

I need help regarding the issue. Please help me if anyone has ever used the here maps SDK in iOS and Swift 3.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: I am doing the required steps but I am getting this error - Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1

Comment: I tried every possible steps mentioned on the web to resolve this issue but I am not able to build it without an error. It seems that there is an error in the file provided by here maps SDK called NMAKit.framework because as soon as I am adding this file, I am getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this steps follow to solve error.

In terminal, goto project's root directory and execute one by one command

```
  find . -type f -name '*.jpeg' -exec xattr -c {} \;
  find . -type f -name '*.png' -exec xattr -c {} \;
  find . -type f -name '*.tif' -exec xattr -c {} \;
```

Clean Xcode and Re Build. Done.

Comment: I actually did all of this. Also, I am struck at the starting point just because of this error.